# How to use a variable value created in an Execute SQL Task in Precedence Constraint Editor?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, execute-sql-task

[image]I need to run n-multiple Execute SQL Task based on n-multiple variable value (isnull true or false). This variable is created in a ssms script in the previous execute sql task (CONDITIONAL QUERY). How can I output the variable value from the ssms script to the conditional expression in ssis?

my two variables are `@beneficiary` and `@gempar`. They either store a date type value or null.

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here, but you can capture the output of a `SELECT` statementin a Execute T-SQL Task my using the `ResultSet` setting in General Pane, and then mapping the individual columns (if using Single Row) or the dataset object (if using Full result set) to a variable in the `Result Set` pane. Or, if you're using a Stored Procedure with `OUTPUT` parameters, you map them in the Parameter Mapping pane (unsurprisingly).

Comment: By Stored Procedure, do you mean a File Connection? Because this is what I am using.

Comment: No, by stored Procedure I mean the SQL Object. You're using an Execute T-SQL Task; you're not querying a file...

Comment: Images of code isn't very helpful to the users, however, in your SQL you don't have any output parameters. As I mentioned, `OUTPUT` parameters are part of a Stored Procedure; you can't have them as part of an inline statement. If you want to use those, you'll need to convert your SQL to a Stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a ResultSet inside the execute SQL Task, and map the result to a variable by following these steps:

1. At the end of SQL Statement add the following line

   ```
   SELECT @benefeciary as benefeciary, @gempar as gempar
   ```
2. In the Execute SQL Task, change the ResultSet option to `single Row`
3. Go To Result Set Tab
4. Map the Column index (starting `0`) to the relevant Variable

   ```
   0 >> benefeciary
   1 >> gempar
   ```

---

For more details, there are many articles describing this process:

1. [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)
2. [Map Result Sets to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-result-sets-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014)
3. [How To Set and Use Variables in SSIS Execute SQL Task](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/)

Comment: Link only answers are generally not well received on Stack Overflow; they often attract down votes, the links can become dead (making them useless to future readers), and there is a specific review option for the removal of them in the low quality queue. To improve your answer, I would suggest adding the relevant parts of the articles you have linked, otherwise this is likely better as a comment.

Comment: @Larnu no problem, i will provide more details

Comment: It is not possible to click on the Add button in the Result Set section. Maybe because the script is a File Connection?

Comment: @BoelsMaxence check that the in the General Tab, the Result Set option is set to `Single Row`.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional query task should have a "Result Set" set to a "Single Row", just like on a screenshot:

[image]

Then just assign your variables to output columns:

[image]

If your query returns two values, you can use ordinal positions,

so ResultName = 0, can be mapped to a `@beneficiary` and ResultName 1 to `@gempar`

More details: [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)

---

**Update:**
The script used in T-SQL task should return values via SELECT, but not via PRINT:

```
--SOME SELECTs..
..
SELECT @benefeciary, @gempar
```

Comment: I am not able to click on the Add button in the Result Set section. I updated the question with the SQL T-Script which is put as file connection in the Execute SQL Task.

Comment: @BoelsMaxence, updated answer, you are using PRINT, it should be SELECT.. Print statements are ignored by SSIS..

Comment: I removed the print from the sql script

Comment: Just add this as the last line:

Comment: Should I use the Parameter Mapping or the Result Set?

Comment: @BoelsMaxence ResultSet

Comment: You do not need in this case parameter mapping, but only result set. Please check my answer above, there is a SELECT you have to include as the last line your SQL script

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [map result set to variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-result-sets-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017), you may also need to set the execution result of the task to the variable using [`ExecValueVariable.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.taskhost.execvaluevariable?view=sqlserver-2017)

Attached is one of my SSIS packages with a variable named HasRecord. Click the `Execute SQL Task` and set the `ExecValueVariable` to the desired variable, `User::HasRecord`.

[image]

[image]